# change mysql timezone to UK

Tags: mysql, php, timezone

I want to change mysql default timezone to UK timezone,

I have no access to mysql config file. Is there any way that I can do this on query level.

So once the query executed then it will save date based on Uk timezone,

Thanks

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/446505/setting-the-timezone-in-mysql-on-every-connection-using-zend-php

Answer (score 1):

client can change its own time zone with this statement:

```
SET time_zone = '+0:00';
```

Comment: is there any way I can change runtime using query?

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file you are loading you can set the timezone with the default-time-zone='timezone' directive e.g.

`default-time-zone='+00:00'`

for UTC. There is more information in the [MySQL timezone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) reference manual

Edit:

To change your timezone on the fly use the `SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'timezone' ;` command e.g.

```
mysql -u root -p
your password

mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| SYSTEM             |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| +00:00             |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: is there any way I can change runtime using query?

Comment: @Avinash: See my edit

Comment: @lain "SET GLOBAL" need super privilege

Comment: @bindbn: which the root account would likely have ?