# Setting the timezone in MySQL on every connection using Zend PHP

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, zend-framework

My company just recent moved our MySQL database to and instance Aamazon Web Service's RDS.

The problem is the application relies on time zone information and the timezone in MySQL (under RDS) is set to UTC and can't be changed.

So I'm wondering how to change it on a perconnection basis in my Zend Framework.

I'm not really sure where to start with this so any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
function setDbTimeZone(Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $dbAdapter, $timeZone)
{
    $dbAdapter->exec("SET time_zone='$timeZone'");
}
```

Usage:

```
$dbAdapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql([
    // ...
]);

setDbTimeZone($dbAdapter, 'US/Pacific');
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Per Connection**

  By zone name

  `SET time_zone = 'US/Pacific';`

  By UTC offset

  `SET time_zone = 'US/Pacific';`

  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html

Comment: This helps a ton. But how exactly would I pass it my Zend Frame work class. I think this is what I actually asking. Maybe I should post this question on a Zend Developers forum.